# HealthKit data does not updating Since iOS14 or watchOS7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit, watchos

I used to getting near real time heartrate from HealtKit written by apple watch work out until iOS13 in active way like below. Apps accesses HealthKit each time and getting near real time heartrate(almost updated each 5seconds).

But in iOS14, apps gets value each time, but it's never updated. I surely started apple watch workout. Then, once go background and back to foreground, apps gets updated heartrate value. But to get another updated value, you have to go background once.

It seems that apple watch pushes data to healthkit when open some apps like settings or developing apps.

How could it solve?

```
  self.awTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getHeartBeatFromAppleWatch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc private func getHeartBeatFromAppleWatch() {
     let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)]
     let query = HKSampleQuery.init(sampleType: self.hkTypeHeartRate, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, resultsHandler: { (query, samples, error) -> Void in
                 if let error = error {
                     NSLog("[updateHeartRateNormal] resultHandler error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                     // error event
                 } else if let samples = samples {
                    // success event
                  }
             })
     self.healthStore.execute(query)
 }
```

In addition, I tried passive way like below, same thing was happend.

```
let distanceQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: self.hkTypeHeartRate, predicate: .none, anchor: nil, limit: 0) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
            print(samples)
        }

        // This is called each time a new value is entered into HealthKit (samples may be batched together for efficiency)
        distanceQuery.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
            print(samples)
        }

        // Start the query
        self.healthStore.execute(distanceQuery)
```